# How to select two words in a paragraph VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a paragraph in word containing:

**"b) Vergabeverfahren Öffentliche Ausschreibung, VOB/A Vergabenummer 13A0295S. "**

Is it possible to select following two words at the same time in this paragraph.

**"b) Vergabeverfahren"** and **"Vergabenummer "**

The reason is I want to change the selection color to red. I Can select one word successfully with this code. But selecting two words is a bit problematic for me.

Here is my code:

```
Selection.Start = singleLine.range.Start
Selection.End = singleLine.range.End


ReplaceText = StrFrmDll ' StrFrmDll contains the paragraph. 


 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
 With Selection.Find
 .Text = ReplaceText
 .Replacement.Text = ReplaceText
 .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
 .ClearFormatting
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Format = True
 .MatchCase = False
 End With
     Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
     Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do two of the Selection.Find's

```
 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
 With Selection.Find
 .Text = Vergabeverfahren
 .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
 .ClearFormatting
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Format = True
 .MatchCase = False
 End With
     Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
     Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed

 Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
 With Selection.Find
 .Text = Vergabenummer
 .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
 .ClearFormatting
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Format = True
 .MatchCase = False
 End With
     Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
     Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed
```